# How to access the method which is defined by the super interface in JSF?

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, managed-bean

I've tried to learn the JSF 2.0 by implementing the managed bean via the NetBeans 7. By overview it contains the property as a data object which implements the interface as the following: -

```
public interface MyInterface1 {
    void setName(String name);
    String getName();
}

public interface MyInterface2 extends MyInterface1 {
   void setPhone(String phone);
   String getPhone();
}

public class MyInfo implements MyInterface2 {
   //...Getter, Setter
}

@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
public class MyManagedBean {

    private MyInfo myInfo = new MyInfo();

    //..Getter, Setter
}
```

When I enter the EL at the JSF/XHTML as

```
#{myBean.myInfo....}
```

the methods which are defined at the Super Interface, the MyInterface1 is not displayed.
I'm not sure if it is a tool limitation or I may do something wrong or not.

Could you please help to advise further? Thank you very much for your help in advance. I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a limitation of the Netbeans editor. I've constantly struggled with similar issues in NB 6.9, code completion would sometimes not work at all, sometimes missing out interfaces/methods, etc. But hey, you can go ahead and type in the method name yourself - it should work.